# Does inotify trigger the IN_DELETE before or after deletion?

Tags: linux, events, file-io, triggers, inotify

I'm trying to backup a file before it gets deleted. Can someone tell me if inotify triggers the event before or after deletion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IN_DELETE is triggered when a file/directory is deleted in the watched directory, ie after the deletion.

Answer (score 0):

but is'it possible to make inotify trigger before each action.

rm -rf /media/disqueExterne/   and inotify send an alert as do a database server before each access  to a record..

here :

[bash command rm -rf /media/disqueExterne ] ---> [system pipe ] ---> direct order ---> [/dev/sdd1 ] ---> files destroyeds

with inotify pretrigger

[bash command rm -rf /media/disqueExterne ] ---> [ system pipe] --> [inotify pretrigger catch ] ---> backup each file ---> securised rm -rf order ---> [/dev/sdd1 ] ---> files destroyeds
is it possible to catch the commands in a system pipe or buffer before sending the order.

[user send a command ] ---> [buffer] ---> order [ action launched]  and after

[user send a command ] ---> // inotify hold data  ---> [inotify action] --- // --> [return to buffer ] ---> order ---> [action  launched ]